# PySide connect a button in HTML to a PySide slot

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyside

Is it possible to use one of the Web classes in PySide to load a local html/JS file which contains buttons, and have those buttons connected to a PySide slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QtWebKit to export a QObject to the JavaScript context and then cast the signal from JavaScript as shown in the following example:

```
├── index.html
└── main.py
```

**main.py**

```py
import os

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class ClickListener(QtCore.QObject):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    listener = ClickListener()

    listener.clicked.connect(lambda: print("clicked"))

    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "index.html")

    w = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    w.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("qt_clicked_listener", listener)
    w.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button id="myBtn">Click me</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
            qt_clicked_listener.clicked();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```